# Chrome Addon photo next to selected text does not display correctly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to create a quick plugin that when I select a text a picture of my extension will appear when I click on it it will take me to another tab and paste the text into the search engine. Unfortunately, after trying, I got stuck with this error:

```
content.js:6 Icon created: <img src=​"chrome-extension:​/​/​fpchckfjbfhmjmpjplcabjlanjmppcma/​icons/​icon.png" id=​"extensionIcon" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 258.391px;​ left:​ 401.625px;​">​
chrome-extension://invalid/:1 
        
        
       GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED
```

this is my project tree.

```
addons
├─ content.js
├─ icons
│  └─ icon.png
└─ manifest.json
```

provide my manifest.json file

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Addons",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Describe Addons",
    "permissions": [
      "storage",
      "activeTab",
      "notifications",
      "tabs"
    ],    
    "action": {
      "default_icon": "icons/icon.png"
    },
    "icons": {
      "48": "icons/icon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ],
    "content_security_policy": {
      "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self';"
    }
  }
```

I tried using contextmenu as well as mouseup but the result was that i kept getting the same error for several hours. here is my actual code.

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
  var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString().trim();

  if (selectedText !== '') {
    var icon = new Image();
    console.log('Icon created:', icon);

    var iconUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL('icons/icon.png');

    icon.src = iconUrl;
    icon.id = 'extensionIcon';
    icon.style.position = 'absolute';

    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();

    icon.style.top = rect.top + window.scrollY + rect.height / 2 + 'px';
    icon.style.left = rect.right + window.scrollX + 'px';

    document.body.appendChild(icon);

    icon.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'moveToNewTab' });
      document.body.removeChild(icon);
    });
  }
});
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You must declare the image in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/manifest/web_accessible_resources/).

Comment: You're right it solved my current problem. Thank you. @wOxxOm